# Unit-testing flink application with streaming data

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-flink

I have a function called windowing() which basically gets streams from kafka-0.9 and do transformations as below :

```
   public void windowing() throws Exception {
            DataStream<EnrichedEnergyMetricSchema> timeStampStream = dataStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MessageTimeStampExtractor(maxTimeLag));
            KeyedStream<EnrichedEnergyMetricSchema,Tuple> ks=timeStampStream.keyBy(StreamingConstants.KEY_BY_VARIABLE);
            ks.timeWindow(Time.seconds(120)).sum("totalConsumed").addSink(sinkFunction);
            env.execute("test program");

        }
```

Unit testing for this code is as follows : 
I used env.readFile() function to read data from file and try to generate streams :

```
 @org.junit.Test
    public void testWindowing() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.setParallelism(1);
        EnergyInputFormat format = new EnergyInputFormat();
        DataStream<EnrichedEnergyMetricSchema> dataStreamSource = env.readFile(format,"teststream");
        Windowing windowing = new Windowing(env,dataStreamSource,sinkFunctionTest);
        windowing.windowing();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        EnrichedEnergyMetricSchema aggregatedValue = objectMapper.readValue(result,EnrichedEnergyMetricSchema.class);
        Long actual = aggregatedValue.getTotalConsumed();
        Long expected = 18L;
        Assert.assertEquals(expected,actual);
    }

static SinkFunction sinkFunctionTest = new SinkFunction<EnrichedEnergyMetricSchema>()  {
        @Override
        public void invoke(EnrichedEnergyMetricSchema enrichedEnergyMetricSchema) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(" result is ::"+result);
            result = enrichedEnergyMetricSchema.toString();
        }
    };
```

Exception what I am getting is :

```
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka://flink/user/jobmanager_1#991060241]
11/28/2016 16:37:18 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
11/28/2016 16:37:18 Source: Custom File Source(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 Source: Custom File Source(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 FileSplitReader_Custom File Source -> Timestamps/Watermarks(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 FileSplitReader_Custom File Source -> Timestamps/Watermarks(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 TriggerWindow(TumblingEventTimeWindows(120000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@72c21b09, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.aggregation.SumAggregator@433d61fb}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:347)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 TriggerWindow(TumblingEventTimeWindows(120000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@72c21b09, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.aggregation.SumAggregator@433d61fb}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:347)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 TriggerWindow(TumblingEventTimeWindows(120000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@72c21b09, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.aggregation.SumAggregator@433d61fb}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:347)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 Source: Custom File Source(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 FileSplitReader_Custom File Source -> Timestamps/Watermarks(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
11/28/2016 16:37:18 Source: Custom File Source(1/1) switched to FINISHED 
11/28/2016 16:37:19 TriggerWindow(TumblingEventTimeWindows(120000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@72c21b09, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.aggregation.SumAggregator@433d61fb}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:347)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to FINISHED 
11/28/2016 16:37:19 FileSplitReader_Custom File Source -> Timestamps/Watermarks(1/1) switched to FINISHED 
11/28/2016 16:37:19 Job execution switched to status FINISHED.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:876)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2146)
    at com.philips.lighting.cheetah.flink.WindowingTest.testWindowing(WindowingTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:130)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I have 2 records in my file and I am injecting the objects using google guice.

Problem is, Windowing is not happening after keyedstream. It's just coming out with NullPointer Exception.

Help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: where in your code do you actually set the result variable that you pass to objectMapper.readValue()?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, I have an inner class and declared result as global varibale. I have edited the post now. you can see the latest changes.

Comment: It still seems like it is the result variable that is null here. Can you verify that?

Comment: Yes. result variable is null beacuse windowedStream<> in windowing() is not giving any value. That's the whole point of posting this question. How to get rid of the NullPointerException.  @Frank Lauterwald

Comment: One thing to check is whether the data source actually reads the data correctly. Another thing that would be interesting to test would be a source that emits your values and then blocks for 2 full minutes. Your source may emit so few elements that the job goes into a finishing state without ever firing a window. This happens for count windows as well, if the total number of input elements for a job is smaller than the count threshold the window never fires. Something similar may be happening here.